# Is it possible to configure a global alias based on a hostname pattern?

Tags: apache-2.2

Considering a web server that hosts several virtualhosts, is it possible to configure a global alias based on a hostname pattern that may also be matched by one of the earlier-defined hosts?

**Some context:** we often use staging domains for our clients on which they can view their website whilst the domain has not yet been configured properly. This makes the virtualhost directives look as following:

```
<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80>
    ServerName myclient.com
    ServerAlias myclient.staging.mycompany.com
    ....
</VirtualHost>
```

**What I want to achieve:**

I'd rather not have the staging domain included in Google results. For this, I'd like to configure an `Alias` directive with `Disallow: /`  when the host name pattern matches `*.staging.mycompany.com`. Preferably, I'd rather not include this in each virtualhost, but configure it on a higher level.

**What I have tried:**

I have tried configuring a custom `VirtualHost` as follows:

```
<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80>
    ServerName staging.mycompany.com
    ServerAlias *.staging.mycompany.com
    Alias /robots.txt /usr/local/apache/htdocs/staging-robots.txt
</VirtualHost>
```

This does not work, because of the fact that the other `VirtualHost` directives are matched and this one is ignored.

What would be the most elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my own problem by including file in each `VirtualHost` as follows:

```
<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80>
    ....
    Include /usr/local/apache/conf/includes/staging-rewrites.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

And in: `/usr/local/apache/conf/includes/staging-rewrites.conf`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*\.myredactedstagingdomain.com$ 
RewriteRule robots.txt /usr/local/apache/htdocs/staging-robots.txt [NC,L]
```

And finally, in my robots file:

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /
```